# Can Emacs' org-mode recognize tags within (instead of just at the endof ) a headline

Tags: emacs, tags, org-mode

I am learning how to use Emacs and `org-mode`, and am wondering whether Emacs can support tags *within* rather than just at the end of headlines (whether natively or through a package or configuration in ~/.emacs).

Put differently, Emacs natively supports tags in this form:

`* This is a headline.     :tag1:tag2:`

Is there a way to get Emacs to recognize tags in the format below in addition?

`* This is a headline with :tag1: and :tag2:.`

I've been searching for answers for several hours, and haven't found this question anywhere else; I'd be grateful for any advice!

Comment: Sorry, but this is not possible without substantially modifying several aspects of `org-mode` yourself.  The reason is that there are many regexp that are baked-into the source code that expect the tags to always be at the end, and changing the location will break many aspects such as highlighting and the org-agenda buffer search results when dealing with tags.  You can, however, remove the right alignment so that the tags immediately follow the title -- customize `org-tags-column` to `0`.  I like a period at the end of the title and two literal spaces beofre tags: `* Active title.  :tag:`

Comment: Thanks, @lawlist! If you turn this into an answer, I'll accept it (after a few days, to allow any other answers with additional info.).
I'm just getting into understanding elisp, so this seems like an ok question for a comment (if not, I can split it off into a separate question): Can elisp handle taking some highlighted text (as in the second example string in my question), finding all tag-like strings within the text, and concatenating them as actual tags at the end of the string? I found the s package, but am curious whether vanilla elisp can do this. I'd be grateful for any pointers.

Comment: The most common search in Emacs is done with `re-search-forward` and `re-search-backward`, and lists are gathered with things like `push` or `append`, and lists can be concatenated with `mapconcat`, or I suppose you could take a string and keep `concat`-enating each search result.  Essentially you would want to visit each heading and use a regexp to isolate the tags, gather the results, and visit the next heading.  The property drawers look like tags, so you need to use a heading regexp.  Have a look at `org-complex-heading-regexp`, `org-heading-regexp`, `org-outline-regexp`.

Comment: Thanks for your advice, @lawlist! I've successfully written a function and posted it in an answer below, in case anyone else comes along looking for similar functionality after learning the answer to this question. I'll still accept your answer if you write it up, though!

Answer (score 0):

The real answer to this question is in @lawlist's comment above, that (to quote @lawlist) it **"is not possible [to get org-mode to recognize tags *within* a line of text instead of at the end of the line] without substantially modifying several aspects of org-mode yourself."**

For this reason, if @lawlist writes the comment up as an answer, I'll accept it. I'm also writing up this additional answer, though, for anyone like me who comes along and, learning this, wants a way to take some text and automatically generate org-mode tags for it. Following the discussion in the comments above, I've written a function in `elisp` below, which allows a user to highlight some text and automatically find any tags within the text (here, in the form `{{tag}}`) and concatenate them in org-mode tag format at the end of the first line.

```
(defvar tag-regexp-for-generating-org-mode-tag-list-from-text "{{\\(.*?\\)}}"
"A regular expression, in double-quotes, used for finding 'tags' within lines of text (these can then be translated into org-mode syntax tags.

For example, in the string \"This text contains the 'tags' {{tag1}} and {{tag2}}\", the default regular expression

\"{{\\(.*?\\)}}\"

would find \"tag1\" and \"tag2\", which could then be transformed into org-mode syntax tags, \":tag1:tag2:\"")

;; Following https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/12335, use just the selected region.
(defun generate-org-mode-tag-list-from-selected-text (beginning-of-selected-region end-of-selected-region)
    "Take a highlighted section of text, find all strings within that text that match the search parameters defined in the variable tag-regexp-for-generating-org-mode-tag-list-from-text (by default, strings of the form {{tag1}} {{tag2}}), and concatenate them into a set of org-mode tags (:tag1:tag2:)

When text is highlighted, the argumentes beginning-of-selected-region and end-of-selected-region will be automatically populated.
"
    (interactive "r") ;; 'r' mode will auto-populate 'beginning-of-selected-region' and 'end-of-selected-region' above with the values of region-beginning and region-end.
    (if (use-region-p) ;; If a region is actively highlighted
        (progn ;; Start a multi-line sequence of commands   
            ;; Following https://learnxinyminutes.com/docs/elisp/, go to the beginning-of-selected-region (here, of the selected region), and do a find-and-replace.
            (setq list-of-tag-strings (list)) ;; Create a blank list, which we'll fill in below.

            (goto-char beginning-of-selected-region) ;; Go to the beginning of the selected region (we'll then search forward from there.

            ;; A regex of "{{\\(.*?\\)}}" below looks for tags in {{this}} form. You can specify any other regex here instead.
            (while (re-search-forward tag-regexp-for-generating-org-mode-tag-list-from-text end-of-selected-region 't) ;; Search forward, but only up to the end-point of the selected region (otherwise, end-of-selected-region could be replaced with nil here).
                (add-to-list 'list-of-tag-strings ;; Add to the list called list-of-tag-strings
                    (replace-regexp-in-string "[[:space:]|:|-]+" "_" (match-string 1)) ;; Since org-mode tags cannot have spaces or colons (or dashes?) within them, replace any of those in the first capture group from the regular expression above ('match-string 1' returns whatever was in the parentheses in the regular expression above) with an underscore.
                    t) ;; Append (first checking for duplicate items) the first capture group from the regular expression above (i.e., what's inside the parentheses in the regular expression) to a list. The t tells the function to append (rather than prepend) to the list.
            ) ;; End of while statement

            ;; Go to the end of the first line of the selected region.
            (goto-char beginning-of-selected-region)
            (end-of-line)

            (if (> (length list-of-tag-strings) 0) ;; If the length of the list of found tags is greater than 0:
                (insert "  " ":" (mapconcat 'identity list-of-tag-strings ":") ":")) ;; Insert two spaces, a ':', the items from the list each separated by a ':', and a final ':'.

            (message "Tags gathered from the selected region (which comprises character markers %d to %d) and printed on the first line of the region." beginning-of-selected-region end-of-selected-region))

        ;; 'Else' part of the statement:
        (message "No region is selected for gathering tags. To run the function, you need to highlight a region first.") 
    ))
```

You can then highlight text like this, and run the function with `M-x generate-tag-list-from-selected-text`:

```
This is a test {{with}} some {{tags}} in it.
This is another test with an {{additional           tag}} and {{one:more}}.
```

This text will then become

```
This is a test {{with}} some {{tags}} in it.  :with:tags:additional_tag:one_more:
This is another test with an {{additional           tag}} and {{one:more}}.
```

Since this is the first function I've written in `elisp`, I used [two](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/12335) [sources](https://learnxinyminutes.com/docs/elisp/) for understanding the basics of elisp syntax, specifically regarding a) using just a selected area of text and b) running find-and-replace operations on that text. Given that the function uses the *generic structure* of the code vs. its specific content, I'm thinking that I'm within my rights to open up the function with a **[CC0 dedication](https://creativecommons.org/publicdomain/zero/1.0/)** (I do this because of StackOverflow's [ongoing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12527/do-i-have-to-worry-about-copyright-issues-for-code-posted-on-stack-overflow) [discussion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/272956/a-new-code-license-the-mit-this-time-with-attribution-required?cb=1) about licensing of code on this site).